# Why doesn't GNOME 3.10 work in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gnome, 14.04

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and want to have GNOME working instead of Unity, I simply typed to console:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell -y
```

Some required packages were installed and **`gdm`** was along them.

I made gdm be the default against lightdm.

However, when I log in I can't really pick ***GNOME*** as desktop enviroment at start login screen. There's *Ubuntu* and *System Default*.

*Ubuntu* actually is Unity and when I pick *System Default* it'll login but anything will be loaded but the wallpaper, not any superior or inferior bar, not any effects.

Just for the record, I tried with lightdm but it won't show any option for choosing a desktop enviroment.

How can I have GNOME (at least 3.10) working properly on my Ubuntu?

Comment: This sounds like perhaps there's a missing file in /usr/share/xsessions. Does the file /usr/share/xsessions/gnome.desktop exist? Also, check for /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/gnome.desktop. If neither of these exists, perhaps you could try installing the `gnome-session` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might help to install all of ubuntu GNOME:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

It will pull in gnome-session like Githlar suggested, and also all other things that may be needed for a smooth experience.

Comment: Yes, actually I installed `gnome-session` and got it to work. What happens if I install `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` now?